# Optimize ST_CoveredBy performance

Tags: postgis, postgis-2.0

I have a PostGIS 2.0.3 table with 113,862 records with multipolygons represented both as geometry and geography. There is a gist index on each of them. I'm running the following queries:

```
SELECT *, ST_AsText(geog) As wkt
FROM ds_pg_data_noise_poly WHERE 
ST_CoveredBy(ST_PointFromText('POINT(12.432404 55.697712)', 4326), geog) 
LIMIT 100;
```

The above query use Geography in a WSG84 coordinate system and returns the correct 8 rows in 33872 ms.

```
SELECT *, ST_AsText(geom) As wkt 
FROM ds_pg_data_noise_poly WHERE 
ST_CoveredBy(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(715692.377 6177776.241)'), geom)
LIMIT 100;
```

The above query use Geometry in a UTM32 coordinate system and returns the correct 8 rows in 10494 ms.

Is there anyway I can optimize the speed of this query? I believe I read somewhere that I could use bounding boxes to decrease the amount of records to iterate. Is this correct, and how would that look? Any suggestions are welcome.

*UPDATE:*

By minimizing the returned columns I managed to reduce the query time to 2168 ms.

```
SELECT noise_cl, noise_in 
FROM ds_pg_data_noise_poly WHERE     
ST_CoveredBy(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(715692.377 6177776.241)'), geom);
```

I still do not find this acceptable, but it is definitely better. As each record is placed within a subset, I can actually reduce the records to iterate even more.

```
SELECT noise_cl, noise_in 
FROM ds_pg_data_noise_poly WHERE
(subset = 'subset1' OR subset = 'subset2') AND 
ST_CoveredBy(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(715692.377 6177776.241)'), geom);
```

The above query returns in 1353 ms. I am still not quite happy with the result. Any suggestions are more than welcome.

Comment: Please post your postgres version and the output of the following two commands: `\d ds_pg_data_noise_poly` and `EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT noise_cl, noise_in 
FROM ds_pg_data_noise_poly WHERE
(subset = 'subset1' OR subset = 'subset2') AND 
ST_CoveredBy(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(715692.377 6177776.241)'), geom)`